# Уникализация изображений на python

Tags: python, обработка-изображений

Каким образом можно обрабатывать изображения на python для того, чтобы они стали уникальными? Думаю лучший вариант это добавить сплошной шум на фото, но незаметный для человека. Плюс чистка метаданных.
...
Или более хороший вариант.
...
"Чтобы картинка стала уникальной, достаточно чтобы гугл картинки ее не идентифицировали с ее исходной версией"

Comment: Зависит от точного определения «уникальности»

Comment: Чтобы картинка стала уникальной, достаточно чтобы гугл картинки ее не идентифицировали с ее исходной версией.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Т.е. четкий критерий  уникальности вы не знаете, а знает только Гугл? Тогда какой ответ вы хотите?

Comment: Совершенно верно. Каким образом я могу рандомно (на небольшое значение) изменить все пиксели в изображении?

Comment: Сформируйте случайную матрицу небольших значений. Сложите ее с исходной картинкой. Все.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом технически происходит сама обработка? Какая библиотека необходима?